# When do you get plusses to your ability modifiers?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, character-levels, character-advancement

I'm starting to play 5e and I cannot for the life of me figure out or find out when characters get plusses to their ability modifiers and feats. What level do you get them?

Comment: I'm afraid I honestly can't figure out what exactly you mean with this question.  Do you mean when does the +X from your ability apply to a roll, or when does the actual ability score go up, or when does the modifier go up?

Comment: The question was edited to try to clear it up. Can you confirm that it still says what you're trying to ask about?

Answer (score 1):

Every Class's description has a feature called *Ability Score Improvement*. They all share this feature at the same levels; 4th, 8th, 12th, 16th, and 19th level all give the character an *Ability Score Improvement*. The exceptions to this are: the *Rogue*, who gets an additional improvement at 10th level, and the *Fighter*, who gets additional improvements at 6th and 14th level.

Feats are another matter. For one thing, they are optional now, and the DM can choose whether or not to have Feats in the game. Provided they are allowed, you can choose a Feat in place of an *Ability Score Improvement* when you get that feature.

I can't find anything general about the *Ability Score Improvement* feature, but the description of how Feats work starts on page 165 of the *PHB* under the section labeled "Feats".

Comment: Rogues are not the only exception, **fighters** get additional ability score improvements at 6th, 14th and 16th level. PHB, p. 71; [PBR](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules), p. 25.

Comment: @sadaqah Ah, I must have accidentally overlooked that. I guess that's the Fighter Bonus Feat chain in action.

Comment: The best quote for *Ability Score Improvement* is probably under 'Beyond 1st Level' in 'Chapter 1: Step-by-Step Character Creation', "When your character gains a level, his or her class often grants additional features, as detailed in the class description. Some of these features allow you to increase your ability scores, either increasing two scores by 1 each or increasing one score by 2. You can’t increase an ability score above 20." PBR, p. 10; PHB, p. 16.